# Only index certain fields from Wikipedia River

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the [Wikipedia River](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-wikipedia)

Is there a way / How can I customize the mapping so that ElasticSearch only index the title fields (I'd still like to access the whole text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is useful more to decide how you index data rather than what you index, unless you set it to `dynamic: false` which means that elasticsearch effectively accepts only the fields that are explicitly declared in the mapping.

The problem is that the wikipedia river always sends a set of fields for every document and this behaviour is not currently configurable, thus there's no way to index only a subset of those fields (e.g. only `title` and `_source`). What you could do is modify your search request so that you get back only the fields that you are interested in, but the content of the index will stay the same.